# one bug that click event of checkbox/radiobutton in emberjs

Tags: checkbox, ember.js, click, checked

checkbox event:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="contents" value="1" {{action 'enable_submit'}} />
```

submit button

```
<button id='submit_btn' class='btn' disabled="disabled">Submit</button>
```

when user click checkbox, remove disabled of submit button

```
$("#submit_btn").removeAttr('disabled')
```

The result is:

> 1, disable status of submit button can be removed normally.
>
> ## 2, the checkbox can't be checked again, it is the same problem on radiobutton

Comment: was my answer what you where looking for? let me know if it helped

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/esepoc/3/edit) for a possible implementation.

Basically every time the checked status of the checkbox changes it triggers the disabled status of the button. This is possible due to the two-way binding ember.js provides for you.

Here the view:

```
App.IndexView = Ember.View.extend({
  disabled: false
});
```

The checkbox:

```
{{view Ember.Checkbox checkedBinding="view.disabled"}}
```

The button:

```
{{#view Ember.Button class='btn btn-warning' disabledBinding="view.disabled"}}Submit{{/view}}
```

This binding behavior can also be defined somewhere else, I've put it on the view for the sake of simplicity.

Hope it helps.